# setActiveSelection() does not work on Android

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile, triggers

This code works fine on the computer sheets but does not work on android sheets.

```
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
  sheet.setActiveSelection(range);
```

So basically, I want cell A1 Alway to be selected even if I click any other cells. When I select the different cells on the computer google sheet, it takes me to Cell A1 and selected after a few seconds, which works fine. But when I select the different cell on Android Sheet, it doesn't take me to cell A1 and is not selected. Any suggestion would be helpful, and thank you in advance.
The whole code is

```
    function onEdit(e) 
{
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data_len = data.length;
   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
  sheet.setActiveSelection(range);
   
  for(var i=0; i<data_len; i++) 
  {
    if(data[i][0] == "HERE!") 
    {
      s.getRange(i+1,2).setValue("Yes");

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to set A1 as the active selection ?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it. I work in the warehouse, I have to scan the parcel and put it on the sheet. I got everything that I need, and it works fine, but I want the A1 cell to stay selected even if I press enter. For example, scan the parcel, tracking ID put on the sheet, and then enter. In the next minute, A1 is still selected, scan the different parcels, replace the tracking ID on the A1 cell, then press enter and repeat and repeat. I got everything that I needed, but I just tried selecting A1, scanning the parcel, then selecting another cell and going back to A1.

Comment: please add that to the question

Comment: Instead of `sheet.setActiveSelection(range);` use `range.activate();`

Comment: @Rubén, your code is the same method as mine but once again, it works on a computer but doesn't work on android.

Comment: They aren't the same method, but anyway, based on what you report and olders posts, there is no way to activate a cell with Google Apps Script using the Google Sheets app. Please checkout the Google Apps Script issue tracker to see if a feature request was already made. If so, star it, otherwise create one.

Comment: I agree with you as i saw someone post and same mention about active cell. Some report work on iphone 7 but not android. RIP Android..

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any need for it as it is not currently being used for anything and it serves no real purpose.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] == "HERE!") {
      sh.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue("Yes");
    }
  });
  sh.getRange("A1").activate();
}
```

Comment: Your code does not work on mine, Your code saying this
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`

Comment: It's not meant to be run from the script editor or a menu.  It's meant to be saved and then you edit the sheet appropriately so that the onEdit trigger calls the function for you.  The trigger also supplies an event object which I used extensively

Comment: I see what you meant,  your code is the same behaviour as my previous code. All I need is to A1 cell to keep selected after I press enter.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I have to use the scanner, and it automatically presses enter after the scan. When I scan the parcel, the track ID will show on Cell A1, then it moves down and selected cell A2 therefore another cell will do something after A1 receive the track ID. I just tired to keep pressing A1 cell to scan different parcels to display different track id.  So I want A1 keep selected after press enter. Like I said my code work on computer but doesn't work on android

Comment: Between cell A3 to over A10, i put function =IF(C3=$A$1, "HERE!",""). 
So If cell column C match with Track id in Cell A1, then Column A will show the word HERE! And app script code, what I have done is to add YES right next to HERE! so YES in the B colunm.  That is why I need to keep A1 selected after pressing enter or the scanner press enter, so I can scan more than 1 parcel in the cell A1

Comment: btw your code look more nice and alway ative cell A1 whenever word Yes appears everytime. I guess i will use your code if im using laptop